# Script in google spreadsheet: shift of column and row index

Tags: google-sheets

I wrote a script which take a part of a cell content (let say cell C4) and put it in another column (same row). The column is determined by the title of the column and a for-loop is used to change the rows. I put the main structure of my code below. Everything is working except that, for example, if I take the content of cell C4 (so row i=2) and it has to be put in B4, in fact it will be put in B3. I have to add 1 to the row and to the column index so that it's in the correct cell. What is strange is that the code get the right column and line indexes when it reads the cells (cell A1 =[0][0]) but when it has to write in a cell it's not the case anymore (like if cell A1 = [1][1]). Do you know why? or do I have a problem in my code? thank's
PS: I'm sure that I don't use "i" for another variable name in the code.

```
function thrs() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
        sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
        range = sheet.getDataRange(),
        values = range.getValues(),
        ...;
    for (var i=2;i<values.length;i++) { // change the row
        var val = values[i][an], // the index "an" is determined by the column title
            ...;
    range.getCell(i, ts).setValue(num); // the index "ts" is determined by the column title and "num" is what I want to write in the cell
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript array indices are 0-based. This is what you use in `values[i][an]`

The Google Spreadsheet indices are 1-based. This is what you use in `getCell(i, ts)`.

Hence, you need to adjust for this disparity: `range.getCell(i+1, ts)`